# Find the correct version of libraries

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to do a static build for an open-source project and I'm getting lots of errors while I try to build it.

How do I find the correct version of a library that the project is using?

I also tried to read the Makefile but I couldn't understand much from it. So is there any workaround or anything like that which makes the work easier?

Comment: Versions are here: https://github.com/EnergyCoin/energycoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt

Comment: Indeed, but they are not the correct ones. So no benefit looking at their docs.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to find it out. It's not just the version. Many libraries can be built with different flags. You have to know the supported versions and necessary flags. For this purpose package managers were invented. Each package has meta information describing the dependencies.

Comment: Well, but you said "You have to know the supported versions and necessary flags" then how can I learn this?

Comment: Someone wrote a code using a library. If you want to use the code you have to use a compatible library. You can't find it out from the code. You can ask the developer, read the documentation or look into the package description. If you can't find a documentation of the dependencies you can try different versions and flags. This can cause crashes, undefined behavior or it works if you're lucky and you found a compatible version.

Comment: I understand thank you also if someone else wants to add something more here please do so.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to find it out. It's not just the version. Many libraries can be built with different flags. You have to know the supported versions and necessary flags. For this purpose package managers were invented. Each package has meta information describing the dependencies.

Someone wrote a code using a library. If you want to use the code you have to use a compatible library. You can't find it out from the code. You can ask the developer, read the documentation or look into the package description. If you can't find a documentation of the dependencies you can try different versions and flags. This can cause crashes, undefined behavior or it works if you're lucky and you found a compatible version.